# Append a defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have that file `my_file.txt` (I only show the beginning) :

```
a    CACAAAAAGCGGCGTGGATTGATATTGTAATACGACTCACTATAGACCAACACTAATAATTATATCACTTCGCCT
b    ACAGGNNNNNCTGCGTCTCAGGCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTAAACAGCAAATTTTATTCATATACTAACCCCGCCT
c    CAGTTTTTTGTCTCAGGCGTTTTTTTTTTTAAAAATTTTTTTTATCCCGTTTTTATAAGGCTATACCTGTCCGCCT
d    CACACAAAAATGAGAGTGGATTGATTATGTAATACGACTCACTATAGGGTCGACAGCTTCGTCTTCGCCGCCTAA
```

I need to look at 3 patterns into the 10 first characters of the second field of `my_file.txt`. I made a dictionary with the patterns I look for.

```
seq={}

seq['bc1']='AAAAAA'
seq['bc2']='TTTTTT'
seq['bc3']='NNNNNN'
```

The subtility is that one line should normally match with
only one pattern of `my_file.txt` if we focus on the 10 first characters. For example, the pattern `AAAAA` will match with the first and 4th line.

I want to get as output a dictionary with the keys of the dictionary `seq` and as values, the corresponding lines of `my_file.txt`. The last condition is that the pattern "GCCT" need to be present into the last 10 characters of the lines ; if not, the line is not added to the dictionary even if the pattern in `seq` is found (here, the pattern is always present into the last 10 characters) :

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'bc1': [['a', 'CACAAAAAAGCGGCGTGGATTGATATGTAATACGACTCACTATAGACCAACACTAATAATTATATCACTTCGCCT\n'], ['d','CACACAAAAAATGAGAGTGGATTGATATGTAATACGACTCACTATAGGGTCGACAGCTTCGTCTTCGCCGCCTAA\n']], 'bc2': ['c', 'CAGTTTTTTGTCTCAGGCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCACAAATAATCCCGTTTTTATAAAAACCTGTCCGCCT\n'], 'bc3':['ACAGGNNNNNCTGCGTCTCAGGCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTAAACAGCAAATTTTATTCATATACTAACCCCGCCT\n']})
```

I have :

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    
    my_dict = defaultdict(list)
    
    pattern='GCCT'
    
    with open("my_file.txt","r") as file:
         for lines in my_file.readlines():
                line=lines.split("\t")
                bar=line[1][0:10]
                tail=line[1][-10:]
                for k,v in seq.items():
                        if v in bar and pattern in tail:
                                my_dict[k].append(line)
```

Then, I extract that dictionary as a csv file with the key as filenames :

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
        with open("output_{}.fna".format(k), "w") as f:
                csv=';'.join([','.join(t) for t in v])
                f.write("%s,%s\n" % (k, csv))
```

The problem I have is : when I look at the output files, I can spot the same line into two files. For example, the line `c XXXXXX` will be added to two files : the one corresponding to bc1 (not OK) and to bc2 (it's OK -> selected on the pattern `TTTTT`) . The reason is : we can spot the pattern `AAAAA` in the middle of the line `c` CAGTTTTTTGTCTCAGGCGTTTTTTTTTTT**AAAAA**TTTTTTTTATCCCGTTTTTATAAGGCTATACCTGTCCGCCT -> So, the selection is not only done on the first 15 characters. I don't understand why.

Any help?

Comment: where `bc1001_5p` comes from? cant see it in the file.

Comment: It comes from the first dictionnary. Actually, if the pattern "CACATATCAGAGTGCG" (associated to bc1001_5p) matches with the first 55 characters of many lines of my_file.txt , so the I will append in my defaultdict as key bc1001_5p and as value the full lines >m64071_201130_104452/22/ccs    CACACATCTCGTGAGAGTGGATTGATATGT .... for example

Comment: `dict` is a builtin class and you have named a variable `dict` clobbering that builtin class. This is a very bad practice.

Comment: You're right; I edited the post.

Comment: I don't understand a few things from your question: 1) First you mention you need to compare the patterns (in seq) with first 10 chars but in the code you use 15 chars (the bar part). 2) you say that a pattern has to match only one line but immediately in the next line you give an contradicting example [saying AAAAAA matches with both line 1 and line 4]. 3) You say you have to compare the tail end to see if it has GCCT but you compare tail (last 10 chars) with  bar (first 15 chars) instead of pattern (GCCT). Can you make your post clearer please, so that we can help you better.

Comment: Sorry for that. It's pretty hard to explain.. I edited. And one line match with one pattern (I switched my mistake)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to find the line that has specific string(like `CACATA`) in the first 15 characters(`CACATAGAGCGCTGC`) of the string, (dna I guess)(`CACATAGAGCGCTGCGTGGATTGATATGTAATACGACTCACTATAGACCAACACTAATAATTATATCACTTCTTAAAATGGCTAATTCATTTTTCTTATCCTTATTAGTGTTATTC`)

In this case, you got too long `seq` in your code.

```py
with open("my_file.txt","r") as file:
        for lines in file.readlines():
                line=lines.split("\t")
                # seq=line[1][0:55]
                seq=line[1][0:15]
                for k,v in barcodes.items():
                        if v in seq:
                                my_dict[k].append(lines)
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice, right. But actually, that doesn't solve the problem.. And yes, it is dna.

Comment: So, your problem is that `CACATA` appears in the first 15 characters of another file (like `output_bc1002_5p.fna`). Right?

Comment: Actually no. It nevers appears at the beginning of the others files, but will appears in the middle of ```output_bc1002_5p.fna``` for example.

Comment: And what's I don't want to get. That's why I do a selection on the beginning of the sequences to separate each sequence properly.

Comment: Sorry. I don't get it. Someone nicer and smarter than me will help your problem. Good luck.